# Why do I get a multilevel array?

Tags: php, arrays

I need an array with a list of names so I simply get them from the database, but when I printed the array I noticed it stores every name into a seperate array. Why is that, and how can I just store them in one?

My code:

```
<?
//  Product names
$producten             = "SELECT `naam` FROM `producten`";
$productencon          = $conn->query($producten);
$productencr           = array();
while ($productencr[] = $productencon->fetch_array());
echo '<pre>';
print_r($productencr);
echo '</pre>';
?>
```

The output of that printed array is this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `fetch_array` will return both the assoc name of the column and the numeric index.

If you want only the name of the column you should use: `fetch_assoc` or if you want only numeric you should use `fetch_row`

`fetch_array` is a combination of both `fetch_assoc` and `fetch_row`

If you want to keep `fetch_array` you can also specify as first param the result type. Default is `MYSQLI_BOTH`.

You check more here: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php

Comment: Alright makes sense, but when I change it into fetch_assoc, it still places every name in a seperate array. Just without the numeric values

Comment: @twan Yes, That's the way it works. Because you can select multiple columns from database.

Comment: Is there an easy way to get all names into a single array?

Comment: I fixed it myself by using `array_map('current', $productencr)` Thanks for helping me on the way!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$output=array();
while ($productencr = $productencon->fetch_array()){
    $output[]=$productencr["naam"];
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
echo '</pre>';
```